# Swift - How do I open a pdf file which location is stored in UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, file, pdf, download, nsuserdefaults

I've been trying to open a file on my app using Swift. It is a PDF file that I have downloaded from the Internet through a URL. The download part worked fine for me but I am unable to figure out a way to open that same PDF file through its local location on my app without having to download it again. I know I can just open it within a web view right after I downloaded it but I am planning to make it so the file can be accessed without Internet; hence why I stored the file location in UserDefaults.

I've read online everywhere and searched for videos on youtube too but can't seem to find any way to accomplish this. Also, please correct me if I should not be using UserDefaults or if it is fine because I don't want to access any servers whatsoever and that seemed like the perfect way to do it.

The code I used so far is this:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDownloadDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask!
var backgroundSession: URLSession!
let name = "Accounting"

@IBAction func startDownload(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://pastpapers.papacambridge.com/Cambridge%20International%20Examinations%20(CIE)/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Accounting%20(9706)/2005%20Nov/9706_w05_qp_4.pdf")!
    downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    downloadTask.resume()
}
@IBAction func pause(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if downloadTask != nil{
        downloadTask.suspend()
    }
}
@IBAction func resume(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if downloadTask != nil{
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if downloadTask != nil{
        downloadTask.cancel()
    }
}
@IBOutlet var progressView: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backgroundSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "backgroundSession")
    backgroundSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let file = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Biology") {
        print(file)       //prints the file location where UserDefaults stores it in
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func showFileWithPath(path: String){
    let isFileFound:Bool? = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)
    if isFileFound == true{
        UserDefaults.standard.set(path, forKey: "Biology")

        let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        viewer.delegate = self
        viewer.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }
}

//URLSessionDownloadDelegate
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appendingFormat("/\(name).pdf"))

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURLForFile.path){
        showFileWithPath(path: destinationURLForFile.path)
    }
    else{
        do {
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
            // show file
            showFileWithPath(path: destinationURLForFile.path)
        }catch{
            print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
        }
    }
}
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){
    progressView.setProgress(Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite), animated: true)
}

//URLSessionTaskDelegate
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                task: URLSessionTask,
                didCompleteWithError error: Error?){
    downloadTask = nil
    progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }else{
        print("The task finished transferring data successfully")
    }
}

//UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController
{
    return self
}
```

}

Comment: You need to post relevant code. Show how you download and store the file. Show how you store the location in UserDefaults. Show how you attempt to open the file later from the local location. Show relevant values of variables. Explain what issues you actually have with the code.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, sorry I have updated the code now to include all the code that I used. Maybe this would help now.

Comment: @Danny Where do you display the file?(can‘t find the line.) I had problems with `WKWebView` and used `PDFView` instead, but that doesn‘t help incase you don‘t show it.